# Group multiple rows together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains the following and I am looking to group them to get the below output. Is it possible?

Input

```
ID    Value1    Value2    Value3
5     Y         NULL      NULL
5     NULL      1         NULL
5     NULL      NULL      USA
5     NULL      NULL      NULL
6     N         NULL      NULL
6     NULL      2         NULL
6     NULL     NULL       GBP
6     NULL     NULL       NULL
```

Output

```
ID     Value1     Value2     Value3
5      Y          1          USA
6      N          2          GBP
```

Comment: Post the original query that produced this result we can fix that. For now simple `Group by` and `Min/ Max` aggregate can you get your result

Answer (score 6):

Group by the `id` and use `max()` to get the non-null value per each group

```
select id, 
       max(value1) as value1, 
       max(value2) as value2, 
       max(value3) as value3
from your_table
group by id
```

BTW you should think about changing you table design. It is not normalized.

Comment: You can also use PIVOT, but I prefer this old-school approach too.